# Loop through multiple lists

Tags: swift

I have three dictionaries structured as `[Int : Int]`. Each dictionary is associated with an object. The key of the dictionary is a value of the object, and the value of the dictionary is how many object of that key should exist. One object holds all of these objects. So it would look at little like this.

```
class Cart {
    var fruit: Fruit?
    var cereal: Cereal?
    var juice: Juice?
}

class Food {
    var key: Int?
    var text: String?
}

class Fruit: Food ...
class Cereal: Food ...
class Juice: Food ...
```

The idea is that the user has entered values for each possible option in text boxes and then a dictionary for each object is made. I need to make carts for every object, and each cart needs to holdas many objects as it can. If I have 6 fruits, 5 cereals, and 6 juices, then there should be 6 carts, one of them missing a cereal.

I have everything working up to figuring out how to actually put them together. Here's my loop.

```
for (key, value) in fruitValues {
    for _ in 0..<value {
        print(realm.objects(Fruit.self).filter("value == \(key)"))
    }
}
```

How can I best loop through one array and get values from the others?

Comment: The Cart class is kind of hard to understand, why doesn't it have arrays instead as properties?

Comment: `realm.objects`, does a solution require Realm? If so then please tag the question properly.

Comment: You need to reface your Cart Class. It have fixed properties. Could you please elaborate about the Cart Module?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The classes are all just quick one's that I came up with as examples. I didn't want to put out any sensitive data about the app out, so I came up with arbitrary names instead. In the actual app, arrays are not an option.

Comment: It does not require realm in the solution. I just included that in case it helped with how people understood how the classes work together.

Comment: @udbhateja Mentioned above, the classes listed were created on the spot to represent the actual classes used. Users will only be able to select up to one of each of the classes to go into 'Cart'. They don't have to have all of the objects filled, but at least one needs to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to solve this, not the most compact solution but I couldn't figure out anything shorter. Assume our 3 dictionaries from the users selection

```
let dictFruit = [1: 2, 2: 4]
let dictCereal = [3: 5]
let dictJuice = [4: 3, 5:2, 6: 1]
```

for this example I use a dictionary as my Food types storage

```
let products = [1: Fruit(key: 1), 2: Fruit(key: 2), 3: Cereal(key: 3), 4:Juice(key: 4), 5:Juice(key: 5), 6:Juice(key: 6)]
```

First step is to flatten out the dictionaries to arrays of Food objects which is done with this function

```
func expandSelected<T: Food>(from dict: [Int: Int]) -> [T] {
    return dict.reduce(into: []) {
        if let food = products[$1.key] as? T {
            $0.append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: food, count: $1.value))
        }
    }
}
```

Which I then used

```
let fruits: [Fruit] = expandSelected(from: dictFruit)
let juices: [Juice] = expandSelected(from: dictJuice)
let cereals: [Cereal] = expandSelected(from: dictCereal)
```

then for the last part I used an old fashioned `for` loop to create the Cart items

```
var carts = [Cart]()
for i in 0..<max(fruits.count, juices.count, cereals.count) {
    let cart = Cart()
    cart.cereal = cereals.count > i ? cereals[i] : nil
    cart.fruit = fruits.count > i ? fruits[i] : nil
    cart.juice = juices.count > i ? juices[i] : nil
    carts.append(cart)
}
```

Comment: The line `if let food = products[$1.key] as? T {` tells me "Cast from '[Int : Int]' to unrelated type 'T' always fails" and I get nothing back from the return statement.

Comment: Did you do exactly as I did? The declaration `let fruits: [Fruit]` tells the compiler that T is Fruit

Comment: Yes. That won't make a difference though, since the function has no idea what object type is coming in.

Comment: @CodyHarness the function worked perfectly for me in the playground but you can of course extract the code and apply it directly to each dictionary